# C++/error"no matching call function

Tags: c++, function, call, match

When compiling the code below, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'diccTrie::iterador::iterador(const diccTrie* const, diccTrie::Nodo* const&)'
```

---

```
class diccTrie{
public:
/* ... */
 class iterador{    
    private:
        const diccTrie* diccionario;
        const struct Nodo* actual;

        friend class diccTrie;

        iterador(const diccTrie* d, const Nodo* n): diccionario(d), actual(n){}
    };

    iterador crearIt() const;
private:

    struct Nodo
        {
            Nodo(const char c) :  padre(NULL), hijos(aed2::Lista<Nodo*>::Lista()), clave(c), significado(NULL) {};

            ~Nodo(){
                delete padre;
                delete significado;
                hijos.~Lista();
            }


            bool operator==(const Nodo& otro) const{
                if(otro.hijos.Longitud() != hijos.Longitud()){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return otro.hijos == hijos && otro.padre == padre && otro.clave == clave && otro.significado == significado;
                }
            }

            Nodo* padre;
            aed2::Lista<Nodo*> hijos;
            char clave;
            const int* significado;
            };
    Nodo* raiz;

};
```

The error occurrs in `diccTrie::clearIt` which is implemented as

```
diccTrie::iterador diccTrie::crearIt() const{
    return iterador(this, raiz);
}
```

Where does the error come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the definition of `iterador`,  `const struct Nodo* actual;` introduced `Nodo` in global namespace as the name is not found, so the declaration of the constructor of `iterador` is in fact `iterador(const diccTrie* d, const ::Nodo* n)`, but not `iterador(const diccTrie* d, const diccTrie::Nodo* n)`.

You can add a forward declaration of `struct Nodo;` before the definition of `iterador` in class `diccTrie`. Then in the declaration of `iterador`'s constructor, `diccTrie::Nodo` would be found.

Comment: hi, thanks....if add a forward declaration of struct Nodo before the definition of iterador class, i get this error:    O\Trie\diccTrie.h|46|error: 'struct diccTrie::Nodo' redeclared with different access|

Comment: I assume you added it after the `public:`, so it is declared as public. You should add it in the private section as it is in fact private. Like this:
`private:struct Nodo;`
`public: class iterador{ ....`

Answer (score 1):

How about making the constructor public?

Comment: Not necessary, as `diccTrie` is a friend of `diccTrie::iterador`.